# find command not working: "illegal option -- n"

Tags: linux, find

my command looks something like this

```
find $PATH -name '$FILE.log' > /tmp/file-list.txt
```

and I keep getting an error message that says

```
find: illegal option -- n
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `$PATH` is a special variable that is meant to contain a colon separated list of directories where to find executables.

Comment: What flavour of _linux_ is that? GNU and busybox `find`, the most commonly found implementations on systems that have Linux as a kernel don't give that wording for unknown options.

Comment: You'd get that error if you ran `find -name` with Solaris `find` (so on Linux, you could get that with the `find` from the heirloom toolchest (a port of OpenSolaris tools))

Comment: use `find $(pwd)` if you want current PATH, not `$PATH` itself

Comment: They are most likely on macOS.

Answer (score 26):

From that error message, I'd bet that

- despite your "linux" tag, you're probably not on a Linux-based system as `find` implementations typically found on Linux-based systems don't use that wording for the errors about unknown options
- the `$PATH` variable is unset (which indicates the shell you run that in is probably the Bourne or Korn shell (AT&T implementation)).

That *illegal option* is the wording typically found on traditional Unix `find` implementations.

Those traditional implementations also *require* at least one file argument before you can use a predicate like `-name`.

Otherwise, `-name` would be taken as options (as opposed to predicates) if it was the next argument after `find`.

And `-n` (the first option in `-name` which is short for `-n -a -m -e`) is not a valid `find` option.

So most likely, the expansion of `$PATH` results in no argument at all.

That would happen in cases where:

1. `$PATH` is unset
2. `$PATH` is set to the empty string
3. `$PATH` contains only space, tab or newline characters (the default value of `$IFS`).

Since `$PATH` is the special variable containing a colon-separated list of directories to look up executables including that `find` command, we can rule out 3 and most probably 2 (unless there's a `find`  command in the current directory), or otherwise you'd get a `find: command not found` error.

When `$PATH` is unset (`1` above), in `execvp()` (as typically used by `env` or `find`'s `-exec` predicate for instance) and in some shells (including the Korn and Bourne shell typically found on those *traditional* OSes), `find` would be found through a search in a default search path (shells like `bash` don't do that but set (though not export) `$PATH` to a default value when it was unset on start-up).

Here, I think you want to:

- use a different variable name than `$PATH` to store the directory name (like `$dir`)
- be sure to quote your variables
- use `${dir:-.}` if you want to default to the current directory if `$dir` is empty or unset.
- (maybe also investigate why the `$PATH` variable is unset which is highly unusual)

So:

```
dir=some-dir
find "${dir:-.}" -name "$FILE.log"
```

Note that it assumes that `$dir` doesn't start with `-` and is not otherwise a `find` operator (like `!`, `(`, `)`) and that `$FILE` doesn't contain wildcards (`*`, `?`, `[...]`) (note the use of double quotes instead of single quotes around `$FILE.log` as I assume you want to find files named `something.log` where `something` is the content of `$FILE` as opposed to files named `$FILE.log` literally).

Comment: On Linux, in Bash, when `PATH` is unset, it does not appear that I can execute any non-builtin commands. Is this different for other shells or for Unix? Also, oddly enough, my version of `find` (`find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2`) prints no error when I try `find  -name foo`.

Comment: @KyleStrand about the default search path, see edit. the OP is probably not using `bash`.  As an extension, GNU `find` treats `find -name foo` as `find . -name foo`. If you want to path a file called `-name` (but that's also the case for `find` that don't have that extension), you need to use `find ./-name -name ...` though some implementations support `find -f -name -f -type -predicates...` (which makes them the only one which can take arbitrary file names as in `find -f "$file" -mtime ...`).

Comment: Wacky! Whatever systems I was using a few years ago must not have had GNU `find`, because I remember being tripped up by needing to include `.` when I first started learning to use `find`. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 8):

`$PATH` is (usually - unless you have redefined it, but that would break a bunch of things) a colon separated list of directories. `find` takes a list of directories separated by spaces on the command line:

```
find /path/to/dir1 /path/to/dir2 -name "$FILE.log"
```

Note also that single quotes inhibit evaluation of variables by the shell, so you probably need double quotes around `$FILE.log` as indicated above.

You can convert `$PATH` to a space-separated list in a number of ways, e.g.:

```
 echo $PATH | sed 's/:/ /g'
```

and use command substitution to get the list into your find command:

```
find $(echo $PATH | sed 's/:/ /g') -name "$FILE.log"
```

Comment: Or just: `IFS=:; set -o noglob; find $PATH -name...`

Answer (score 1):

I landed here when I googled for the same error message "illegal option -- n"

I'm on MacOS, and my team are on Linux/Windows. Their version of `find` seems to be more permissive:

The Broken command was:

```
find -name "*.jsonnet"
```

We fix it by introducing a dot for the first argument:

```
find . -name "*.jsonnet"
```

Comment: Yes, the GNU implementation of `find` allows for leaving out the search path(s) and will instead default to using the current directory as the search path. This is, however, not what this question is about, as you can see that the user in the question uses `$PATH` (unquoted) as the search path.  It is possible that the user in the question is using a standard compliant `find` implementation (i.e. not GNU), but the question is why the utility seems to be ignoring the search path, which e.g. Stéphane's answer goes into some depth about.

Comment: @Kusalananda I think the original poster may have been using `$PATH` and `$FILE` as generic placeholders for the question, not in reality (notice `$FILE` is inside the single quotes for the `-name` argument). On that basis this answer is as valid as any other

Comment: @ChrisDavies Ah, ok. In that case, this answer should probably mention that as an assumption, to connect the answer with the question. Otherwise, it's just a generic node about the fact there are different `find` implementations, and they sometimes behave differently.